# Efficiently paginating a table with multiple Primary Keys

Tags: mysql

I usually paginate database tables by ordering by the Primary Key Column, with a query like `ORDER BY id WHERE id > 12000 LIMIT 1000` which does not noticeably slow down as you get further into the database, unlike using `OFFSET` which does.

I would like to be able to paginate databases on tables that contain multiple Primary Key's just as fast, however, I'm not sure how I would write a query like this, as both columns could have ordering that is not related to each other.

Is there a known efficient way to paginate databases with multiple pk's?

Comment: Yes sorry, not thinking :)

Comment: Also, note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless.

Comment: (and I assume you mean composite (or compound) PRIMARY KEY)